# How do I edit created_at from twitter json API

Tags: php, json

I have successfully fetched data from twitter API in the form of JSON. But the time provided by twitter is still not in the dateformat I need, so I think I have to edit it first. The problem is I don't know how to edit a JSON file with PHP.

[image: Here is what twitter API will give in the form of json]

Now if I want to edit the 'created_at', how do I do it? So far, here's what I got.

```html
$results = search($query);

header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$results= json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $results;
file_put_contents('json_result.json', $results);

$contents = file_get_contents('json_result.json');
$contentsDecoded = json_decode($contents, true);
echo $contentsDecoded['statuses']->created_at;
foreach ($contentsDecoded['statuses'] as $tweet) {
 $date = new DateTime($tweet->created_at);
    $formatted_date = $date->format("d-m-Y");
    echo "Date ".$formatted_date;
}
```

I still get error saying that it's a property of non-object...

Comment: Why do you want to edit it, instead of just changing the output format?

Comment: Exactly what @Vuldo said

Comment: As @Perry mentionned, just parse it when you have to display it on the screen. It's an ISO notation, you won't get trouble by keeping it like that. If you need to display it multiple times, just create a function for that.

Comment: @AnnaRG I added it as answer, you can mark it as resolved for anyone having the same question

Answer (score 0):

Edit it before putting it in the file instead of putting it, getting it again, saving again.

Comment: yeah, but how? The code I posted doesn't work, it says there's trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `$results` is an array? You can edit this array before encoding it

Comment: I don't understand, can you expand it more?

Comment: I don't get something why do you fetch from API, encode and save what you fetched, and then open it again decode, try to edit and resave?

Comment: I kind of wrote the code, then see if it works and if it doesn't I put another code on top of it, etc. Sorry if that's been confusing. I mean to fetch from API, edit, encode, then save it. That's at least what I am aiming for.

Comment: The echo part, I am still trying to figure out if it's working, if it is I will encode and save it. But it doesn't and there's error instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in one of these lines:

```
echo $contentsDecoded['statuses']->created_at;
foreach ($contentsDecoded['statuses'] as $tweet) {
```

Either $contentsDecoded['statuses'] has property created_at or is an array
So accessing property created_at of an array is not valid. Try to remove that line